# Calculating moving average for values in a dictionary with keys in a specific range

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, moving-average

So far this is my solution. I wonder if there is some more elegant/efficient way?

```
import datetime as dt

example = {dt.datetime(2008, 1, 1) : 5, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 2) : 6, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 3) : 7, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 4) : 9, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 5) : 12, 
dt.datetime(2008, 1, 6) : 15, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 7) : 20, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 8) :     22, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 9) : 25, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 10) : 35} 

def calculateMovingAverage(prices, period):
    #calculates the moving average between each datapoint and two days before (usually 3! datapoints     included)
    average_dict = {}
    for price in prices:
        pricepoints = [prices[x] for x in prices.keys() if price - dt.timedelta(period) <= x <= price]
        average = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, pricepoints) / len(pricepoints)
        average_dict[price] = average
    return average_dict

print calculateMovingAverage(example, 2)
```

I am not sure, if I should use list-comprehension here.

There is probably some function for this somewhere, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for other interesting ways to solve the problem, here is an answer using *itertools*:

```
import datetime as dt
from collections import deque
from itertools import tee, islice, izip

def dayiter(start, end):
    one = dt.timedelta(days=1)
    day = start
    while day <= end:
        yield day
        day += one

def moving_average(mapping, window, dft=0):
    n = float(window)
    t1, t2 = tee(dayiter(min(mapping), max(mapping)))
    s = sum(mapping.get(day, dft) for day in islice(t2, window))
    yield s / n
    for olddate, newdate in izip(t1, t2):
        oldvalue = mapping.get(olddate, dft)
        newvalue = mapping.get(newdate, dft)
        s += newvalue - oldvalue
        yield s / n

example = {dt.datetime(2008, 1, 1) : 5, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 2) : 6, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 3) : 7, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 4) : 9, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 5) : 12,
dt.datetime(2008, 1, 6) : 15, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 7) : 20, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 8) :     22, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 9) : 25, dt.datetime(2008, 1, 10) : 35}

for ma in moving_average(example, window=3):
    print ma
```

The ideas involved are:

- Use a simple generator to make a date iterator that loops over consecutive days from the lowest to the highest.
- Use *itertools.tee* to construct a pair of iterators over the oldest data and the newest data (the front of the data window and the back).
- Keep a running sum in a variable *s*.  On each iteration, update *s* by subtracting the oldest value and adding the newest value.
- This solution is space efficient (it keeps no more than *window* values in memory) and it is time efficient, one addition and one subtraction for each day regardless of the size of the  window.
- Handle missing days by defaulting to zero.  There are other strategies that could be used for missing days (like using the current moving average as a default or adjusting *n* up and down to reflect the number of actual data points in the window).

Comment: Thanks, that looks really promising and moreover helps me advancing with my python skills. But I still have to figure out a way to use the itertools more often.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using list comprehension in this case is that its inefficient to search through the entire set of prices in every iteration of your loop. The list comprehension in your code checks every element of `prices.keys()` on every iteration of the `for price in prices:` loop.

What you really want to do is take advantage of the fact that dates are sequential, and process them in order. That way when you eliminate a date from consideration on the current iteration of the loop, you can eliminate it from consideration in all subsequent iterations of your loop.

Here's an example:

```
def calculateMovingAverage(prices, period):
    dates = list(prices.keys())
    dates.sort()
    total = 0.0
    count = 0
    average_dict = {}

    for i, d in enumerate(dates):
        # search through prior dates and eliminate any that are too old
        old = [e for e in dates[i-count:i] if (d-e).days > period]
        total -= sum(prices[o] for o in old)
        count -= len(old)

        # add in the current date
        total += prices[d]
        count += 1

        average_dict[d] = total / count

    return average_dict
```

Instead of checking every element of `prices.keys()` on every iteration of the loop, this code searches back from the current date through the list of dates that are included in `total`. When it finds a date that's too old, it removes it from `total` and since we're processing the dates in order, it never needs to look at that date again.

Comment: That was exactly the problem I was looking for. I knew, that I missed something, but I didn't know right away what the problem was. Thanks!